# I want to launch A quicksetting tile from command line using 'am start "

Tags: android, screenshot, shortcut, tile

The app name is screenshottile[no root] and I want to take a screenshot by swiping.
For that I use xposed edge but I dont want to use build in normal screenshot.

I tried this in xposed edge command shell

am start -n com.github.cvzi.screenshottile/com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.activities.TakeScreenshotActivity

but not working

### This is the app androidmanifest

```
<uses-permission android:maxSdkVersion="28" android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS"/>
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS"/>
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.settings.CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS"/>
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE"/>
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.settings.ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS"/>
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
    </intent>
</queries>
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/backup_rules" android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true" android:extractNativeLibs="false" android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules_old" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:localeConfig="@xml/locales_config" android:name="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.App" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Transparent">
    <activity android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.activities.MainActivity" android:taskAffinity="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.task" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.shortcuts" android:resource="@xml/shortcuts"/>
    </activity>
    <activity android:exported="false" android:name="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.activities.TutorialActivity" android:parentActivityName="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.activities.MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
    <activity android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.activities.NoDisplayActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"/>
    <activity android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.activities.DelayScreenshotActivity"/>
    <activity android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.activities.TransparentContainerActivity"/>
    <activity android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.activities.SettingsActivity" android:taskAffinity="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.task" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
    <activity android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:exported="true" android:name="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.activities.SettingDialogActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE_PREFERENCES"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.activities.AcquireScreenshotPermission"/>
    <activity android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.activities.TakeScreenshotActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.activities.PostActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
    <service android:exported="true" android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection" android:icon="@drawable/ic_stat_name" android:label="@string/tile_label" android:name="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.services.ScreenshotTileService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:description="@string/tile_floating_subtitle" android:enabled="@bool/accessibility_service_enabled" android:exported="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_tile_float" android:label="@string/tile_floating_label" android:name="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.services.FloatingTileService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:enabled="@bool/accessibility_service_enabled" android:exported="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.services.ScreenshotAccessibilityService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.accessibilityservice" android:resource="@xml/accessibility"/>
    </service>
    <service android:exported="false" android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection" android:icon="@drawable/ic_stat_name" android:label="@string/tile_label" android:name="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.services.BasicForegroundService"/>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.IntentHandler">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.SCREENSHOT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:label="@string/left_screenshot_right_menu" android:name="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.SimpleWidgetBoth">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/simple_widget"/>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:label="@string/take_screenshot" android:name="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.SimpleWidgetScreenshot">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/simple_widget"/>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:label="@string/open_settings" android:name="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.SimpleWidgetSettings">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/simple_widget"/>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:label="@string/setting_floating_button" android:name="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.SimpleWidgetFloatingButton">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/floating_button_widget"/>
    </receiver>
    <service android:exported="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.assist.MyVoiceInteractionService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_VOICE_INTERACTION">
        <meta-data android:name="android.voice_interaction" android:resource="@xml/interaction_service"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.voice.VoiceInteractionService"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.assist.MyVoiceInteractionSessionService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_VOICE_INTERACTION"/>
    <uses-library android:name="androidx.window.extensions" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-library android:name="androidx.window.sidecar" android:required="false"/>
    <provider android:authorities="com.github.cvzi.screenshottile.androidx-startup" android:exported="false" android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider">
        <meta-data android:name="androidx.emoji2.text.EmojiCompatInitializer" android:value="androidx.startup"/>
        <meta-data android:name="androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer" android:value="androidx.startup"/>
    </provider>
</application>
```